# ScrollView can host only one direct child with relativelayout

Tags: android, scrollview

My layout results in the error "ScrollView can host only one direct child" when using RelativeLayout.

I want to add a scroll view after a toolbar. Everything inside the ScrollView should be scrollable vertically, but when I try this code, it results in the aforementioned error "ScrollView can host only one direct child with relativelayout".

### The `Layout.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    //Scroll view starts here 
        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/view_toolbar" />

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/grey_868686">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="Most Download"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:paddingRight="8dp"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="More"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:paddingRight="8dp"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:onClick="onOtherVideo"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_video_terbaru"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/grey_868686">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="Funny Video"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:paddingRight="8dp"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="More"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:paddingRight="8dp"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:onClick="onOtherVideoFunny"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_funny_video"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/grey_868686">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="Religy Video"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:paddingRight="8dp"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="More"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:paddingRight="8dp"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:onClick="onOtherReligyVideo"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_religi_video"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/grey_868686">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="Others Video"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:paddingRight="8dp"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="More"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:paddingRight="8dp"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:onClick="onOtherMoreVideo"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_others_video"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Answer given by Md.ibrahim khalil is absolutely right,

Try by replacing your layout with this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    //Scroll view starts here

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/view_toolbar" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/grey_868686">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                    android:paddingRight="8dp"
                    android:text="Most Download"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:onClick="onOtherVideo"
                    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                    android:paddingRight="8dp"
                    android:text="More"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv_video_terbaru"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/grey_868686">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                    android:paddingRight="8dp"
                    android:text="Funny Video"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:onClick="onOtherVideoFunny"
                    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                    android:paddingRight="8dp"
                    android:text="More"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv_funny_video"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/grey_868686">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                    android:paddingRight="8dp"
                    android:text="Religy Video"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:onClick="onOtherReligyVideo"
                    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                    android:paddingRight="8dp"
                    android:text="More"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv_religi_video"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/grey_868686">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                    android:paddingRight="8dp"
                    android:text="Others Video"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:onClick="onOtherMoreVideo"
                    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                    android:paddingRight="8dp"
                    android:text="More"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv_others_video"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Many Thanks Dhruv, thats works,,just add orientation in additional LinearLayout..

Answer (score 2):

take a relative layout or linear layout then put all view into it and then wrap this relative layout with scroll view 
your problem will be solved.

Comment: thanks Md.Ibrahim..you can see that all of relativelayout is inside Scrollview and set to wrap_content.. :)